# Can't access index.html from app.py using Flask in Python (different folders)

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using Python with Flask and am trying to connect the *index.html* inside *app.py*, so that the home route will be *index.html*. I have set a virtual environment and installed Flask.

The project folder looks like this:

```
|-- project folder
    |-- .venv
    |-- back
        |-- app.py
    |-- front
        |-- templates
            |-- index.html
```

I tried using ChatGPT, but it just kept saying check folders, names, etc. When I put the templates folder inside the back folder (with *app.py*), it worked. But I need the *index.html* to be inside the front folder.

Comment: I forgot to put the code.
here is the app.py code:

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

app.template_folder = 'project/front/'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


here is the index.html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Flask App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Flask App</h1>
    <p>This is a sample template.</p>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there.

Comment: Please put the code in the body of the question, using code block

Comment: The template_folder path is relative to the root folder (`back` in your case). `app.template_folder = '../front/templates’` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following with `flask run` or `python back/app.py` from the project folder root context.

back/app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template  # 2.2.3
from os import path


app = Flask(__name__)

# ../front/templates
app.template_folder = path.join('..', 'front', 'templates')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```bash
$ tree
.
├── back
│   └── app.py
└── front
    └── templates
        └── index.html
```